# Running an exe with dynamic arguments

Tags: powershell, dynamic, arguments

I would like to execute this command:

```
dot -Tjpg C:\wamp\www\schoolmate\pixy\graphs\xss_index.php_1_min.dot > C:\wamp\www\schoolmate\pixy\graphs\xss_index.php_1_min.jpg
```

For all the files in the directory. The names of the output files should be the same as the input file except for the extension.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work (untested):

```
get-childitem c:\wamp\www\schoolmate\pixy\graphs\*.dot | % {
    & dot -Tjpg $_ > "$($_.Directory)\$($_.BaseName).jpg"
}
```

Comment: pssst.... is the slash in the string backwards.. and I think you mean `$_.basename`

Comment: @Matt Thanks. I did mean `basename`. I'm not sure the slash direction matters but I fixed it anyway.

Comment: For powershell it would not matter but for that app it might

Comment: it says `error: dot can't open C:\..\xss_index.php_1_min.jpg` this file doesn't exist so it is no wonder. dot creates this file from the .dot file

Comment: Oops, missed the redirection.

Comment: well, now it runs and creates the files. except that the pictures are not really pictures. I guess some parameter is wrong